# how to set css height while keeping inherit size (hot to offset height)

Tags: html, css

I did some research, but can't seem to find an answer. I have a text, witch displays way below the form. I'm wondering how I can offset the height of that form in css, because this is a global css file. If I set the height, if displays correctly, but if I add another input, it overlaps. I tried offsetHeight, but that seems to return an error in the css file, that function seems to not exist in style. `transform:offsetHeight(-20px);` seems to do nothing. this is what my css looks like:

```
form{
    line-height: 0.2;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

how would I change the height, while still keeping it adjusted to the container?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Please look at: [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: nevermind, the problem was, I accidentally added extra spaces in my html